# Will Flink lose some old Keyed State when changing the parallelism

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Will Flink lose some old Keyed State when changing the parallelism, like 2 -> 5, or 5 -> 3?

Answer (score 1):

No, Flink will not lose any state (keyed or otherwise) when rescaling. All that rescaling does is to keyed state is to redistribute the data by changing the mapping from key groups to task slots.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. If we don't set the max parallelism, and we change the parallelism to a very big num, will the state loss?

Comment: You won't be able to set the actual parallelism to something higher than the max parallelism (which defaults to 128). So in order to increase the parallelism beyond that limit, you'll have to either drop the state or use the State Processor API to modify the max parallelism.